# Classes and arrays as parameters

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am creating a class named Vehicle and subclass called Tesla. Both classes receive an array as within the constructor parameter. I was unsure if I should use the spread operator in this case. My question is, how do I extract the values from the arrays and set them as properties for the individual classes?

I have tried using the spread operator as well as indexing but that has not worked for me.

```
  class Vehicle{
    constructor(...args){ 
        let arr = Array.from(args)

        this.wheelTotal = arr[0]
        this.energySource = arr[1]
        this.manufacturer = arr[2]
        this.isOn = false
  }

  getSpec(key){
         if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      return this[key]
    }
  }
 }

class Tesla extends Vehicle{
  constructor(...args){
  let arr2 = Array.from(...args)
  super(...args);
              this.milesPerCharge = arr2[0]
      this.model = arr2[1]
      this.chargePercentage = arr2[2]

  }
  minutesToFullCharge(){
      return 100 - this.chargePercentage
  }
}


describe('Tesla', () => {
let teslaCar;

beforeEach(() => {
  teslaCar = new Tesla([300, 'Model S', 50, 100, [[4, 'electric', 'Tesla']]]);    
});

it('should have properties specific to a Tesla such as MPC (miles per charge) and Model', () => {
  expect(teslaCar.milesPerCharge).toBe(300);
  expect(teslaCar.model).toBe('Model S');
  expect(teslaCar.chargePercentage).toBe(50); // 50% charged
  expect(teslaCar.minutesToCharge).toBe(100); // 100 minutes for a full charge
});

it('should have all properties of a Vehicle instance', () => {
  expect(teslaCar.wheelTotal).toBe(4);
  expect(teslaCar.energySource).toBe('electric');
  expect(teslaCar.manufacturer).toBe('Tesla');
  expect(teslaCar.getSpec('wheelTotal')).toBe(4);
});
```

Comment: I'd pass in an 'options' object instead of an array: `new Vehicle({ wheelTotal: x, energySource: y, manufacturer: z })` - that would make it more intuitive in my opinion. The class can then use the named keys to set class props: `this.wheelTotal = options.wheelTotal` or if the constructor destructures the object to begin with: `constructor({ wheelTotal, etc... }) { this.wheelTotal = wheelTotal ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass them arrays of arguments, then you don't have to do anything special with it. Just

```
  class Vehicle{
    constructor(arr) { 
        this.wheelTotal = arr[0];
        this.energySource = arr[1]; // etc.
  }
```

That's all.

Although frankly I don't see the appeal of this pattern. Simply name the arguments: `constructor(wheelTotal, energySource, manufacturer) {//...`. Or use a configuration object, which helps keep order with arbitrarily many (potentially optional) parameters: `constructor({ wheelTotal, energySource, manufacturer }) {//...`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: solution code tested in repl.it]

Was able to assign properties by putting the params in brackets to indicate an array. I did the same for the subclass.